# Force expression in certain form

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, wolfram-alpha-queries

Is there a function in Mathematica to force an expression to be transformed into a given form. For example `f[x]` is a function of `x` with known symbolic expression, and the goal is to find *constants* `A` and `B`  such that `f[x] = A*x + B`.

Is yes, is this also possible in Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: This is sorta kinda vague. If `f[x]` is indeed linear, then yes; otherwise, where are `A` and `B` supposed to come from?

Comment: The actual case was having is `f[x] = A + B/x`, so I wondered if Mathematica can determine if an expression can be written in that form.

Comment: Perhaps `Reduce[f[x] == a /x + b, {x}] // FullSimplify` could be a start. Also please update your question to ask exactly what you need.

Comment: WolframAlpha does not understand user defined functions, so no this is not possible in WolframAlpha. In Mathematica you might try adapt this example to if it can do what you want: f[x] = Sin[x]* x + Tan[3]; f[x] /. {a_* x + b_ -> A* x + B} will then display B + A x. Or possibly f[x] /. {a_* x + b_ -> HoldForm[A* x + B]} which returns A x+B. But that does not assign any values to A or B that you can later use, it just successfully does the substitution and displays that. If you need more or different results then please edit your question to be more precise and detailed.